# How to run specified terminal command from context menu on right clicked folder?

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, finder, context-menu

I'm quite happy I found out about Finder > right-click > "New Terminal at Folder". To make it perfect, I'm looking for a way to run a specified command right after. Automator doesn't seem to have such a feature available. Do you know about any other way to do it?